# Google Chrome closing tabs instead of quiting application

Tags: macos, google-chrome

When I click the close button on Google Chrome, it closes all tabs instead of exiting and remembering the open tabs on next launch. Any way to fix this ?

I expect the X button to close the app. 
I can only do that if I select `quit` (from menu or by keyboard shortcut).

Comment: what Chrome version is it ? what is your os x? which x do you use ? the one on the tab.

Comment: + do you have any tab/window-related extensions?

Comment: Macs work differently than Windows machines. It's just a matter of getting used to the differences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is the way most apps behave on Mac OS X.

The red x button in the corner of the screen closes the window, while choosing `Quit` from the menu or clicking <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> will close the app.

There is no way to *"fix this"* because that is the way the app is meant to behave.

Comment: That's the answer but it's not a good user experience. It's 2019 and neither Google or Apple have fixed this. Makes me want to return to GNOME

Comment: If this behaviour were to be changed, that should be done by Apple. From Google's perspective, this is the most appropriate and most consistent way (compared to other OS X apps) for their app to behave. I would not expect Google to address this issue.

Answer (score 6):

> When you click the `x` Button, then the current window is getting closed.

A workaround to reopen the Tabs is via the Menu:

[image: Chrome File Menu]

So when you close the window via the red x button, **Chrome is still active**. You can then click on the dock icon, and then go to `File`->`Menu` and click on `Reopen Closed Tab`. Alternatively you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to quickly reopen closed tabs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want chrome to remember the tabs which you closed, you can enable it in chrome settings by going to 'on startup' and choose 'continue where you left off'. When you open chrome, the closed tabs should open automatically.

Comment: This does not work when closing with red x button